# Ckan recline_grid_view plugin not found

Tags: ckan

I'm working on CKAN, but despite setting the recline_grid_view entry in production.ini the same is not being displayed.

The recline_grid_view is a plugin that needs to be installed with pip?

Answer (score 1):

[recline_grid_view](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.5.2/maintaining/data-viewer.html#datastore-grid) is packaged with CKAN and doesn't need to be installed separately. However it requires that the data has been uploaded into the [DataStore](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.5.2/maintaining/datastore.html), which is usually done via DataPusher (see previous link) so both these need to be installed and configured. You also need to ensure that the preview has been created for your resource, either by configuration of default views or by manually creating it in the management section for the resource.